# how to check the value of an array in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

```
$result=array();
$count = count($days);
for($i=0;$i<$count-1; $i++)
    {   
    $bookDate = $days[$i];
    $fromDate = $this->booking_model->Get_BookedDate($bookDate,$roomname);                                      
    if ($fromDate != 0)
    {
        $result[] = $bookDate;  
    }                   
}
return $result;
```

This is my codeigniter controller function here I want to check the value of $fromDate is zero or not. I am getting the array like this

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( ["2013-04-27" between fromDate and toDate] => 1 ) )
```

I am very new to codeigniter. Thank you for any help.

Comment: why you are comparing in the foreach loop only compare it outside and are you sure only one match of date output will come..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         $result=array();
         $count = count($days);
         for($i=0;$i<$count-1; $i++)
            {   
$bookDate = $days[$i];
$fromDate = $this->booking_model->Get_BookedDate($bookDate,$roomname);                                                      
if (!empty($fromDate[0]['"'.$bookDate.'" between fromDate and toDate']))
        {
        $result[] =$bookDate;   
        }                                                                   
              }
     return $result;
```

Try this.IT may help you

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `empty()` function.

```
if(!empty($fromdate)) { //if $formdate is empty or 0 or false the loop won't be executed
  //Your code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($fromDate))
               {
            $result[] = $bookDate;  
        }
```

Try this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply The loop is executing if Array ( [0] => Array ( ["2013-04-27" between fromDate and toDate] => 0 ) ) and Array ( [0] => Array ( ["2013-04-27" between fromDate and toDate] => 1 ) )

Comment: I want to execute the statement if the array value is 1 and not to execute the statement if the array value is 0